# when i store function submit from create blade i get this error "Array to string conversion"

Tags: laravel-5

This is my controller in store function save for ministries table.

```
$ministries = new Ministry;

    $ministries->country_id = $request->country_name;
    $ministries->township_id = $request->township_name;
    $ministries->city_id = $request->city_name;
    $ministries->division_id = $request->division_name;
    $ministries->ministryCode = $request->ministry_code;
    $ministries->ministryName = $request->ministry_name;
    $ministries->ministryNameMm = $request->ministry_mm_name;
    $ministries->address = $request->address;
    $ministries->phone = $request->phone;
    $ministries->fax = $request->fax;
    $ministries->email = $request->email;
    $ministries->website = $request->website;
    $ministries->save();
    $ministries_id = $ministries->id;
```

this is save for other table(contact_persons)

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($request->position_id); $i++) { 

         $contact_persons = new ContactPerson();

         $contact_persons->responsibility_id = $request->responsibility_id[$i];
         $contact_persons->position_id = $request->position_id[$i];
         $contact_persons->country_id = $request->email[$i];
         $contact_persons->township_id = $request->email[$i];
         $contact_persons->city_id = $request->email[$i];
         $contact_persons->division_id = $request->email[$i];
         $contact_persons->customer_id = $request->email[$i];
         $contact_persons->address = $request->email[$i];
         $contact_persons->home_phone = $request->email[$i];
         $contact_persons->mobile = $request->email[$i];
         $contact_persons->email = $request->email[$i];
         $contact_persons->ministries_id = $ministries_id;
         $contact_persons->save();
     }
```

please how to solve and thanks.

Comment: add your blade code too

Comment: print you $request and check what's the outcome